# Use of uninitialized value in Perl Regular Expression compilation

Tags: perl

I have the following code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::File;
use Bio::SeqIO;

my ($file1) = $ARGV[0];
my ($file2) = $ARGV[1];

my $fh1 = IO::File->new("$file1")|| die "Can not create filehandle";
my $fh2 = IO::File->new("$file2")|| die "Can not create filehandle";

my @aligned_array = ();

while(my $line1 = $fh1->getline){

    chomp($line1);

    if (($line1 =~ /^match/)||($line1 =~ /^-/)) {

        next;

    }
    else {

        my @line_array = split(/\s+/, $line1);
        push(@aligned_array, $line_array[9]);

    }

}

my $fio1 = IO::File->new("> chimeric_contigs.txt")|| die "Can not create filehandle";
while(my $line2 = $fh2->getline) {
    my $count = 0;
    chomp($line2);

    for my $aligned (@aligned_array) {
        # print $line2.$aligned."\n";
        if ($line2 =~ m/$aligned/) {

            $count++;
        }
    }

    if ($count >= 2) {

        print $fio1 $line2."\n";
    }

}

$fio1->close;
```

and I keep getting the same error

Use of uninitialized value in regexp compilation at /gscuser/rfujiwar/bin/find_chimeric_contigs_blat.pl line 41

This is line 41: if ($line2 =~ m/$aligned/) {

both $line2 and $aligned are defined because I can print them no problem. Please help.

Comment: And what do you get when you print them?

Comment: The proper string that I was expecting

Comment: Contig0.3Contig872.1
Contig0.3Contig872.1
Contig0.3Contig872.1
Contig0.3Contig872.1
Contig0.3Contig873.1 etc... This is the result of uncommenting # print $line2.$aligned."\n";

Comment: Are all elements of `@aligned_array` defined?  Before line 41 put in `next unless defined $aligned;`.

Comment: You're welcome.  I've re-posted my comment as an answer below.  If you could accept the answer (by clicking on the check mark), I'd greatly appreciate it.  :)

Answer (score 4):

(Reposted from the comments, since this ended up solving the issue)  Are all elements of `@aligned_array` defined? Before line 41 put in `next unless defined $aligned;`.

Answer (score 2):

You'll see this error if $line_array[9] is uninitialized when you push it onto @aligned_array:

> ```
>     my @line_array = split(/\s+/, $line1);
>     push(@aligned_array, $line_array[9]);
> ```

In other words, split isn't finding ten space-separated elements in $line1 (and $#line_array is less than nine). So don't add this line to the array, or fix the input in $file1.